# Spring MVC - How to make sure that form submit path is not there in URL post form submit?

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a question on Spring MVC. I have a form where I take some values from user. And then on submit call action (say addTaskAction). It calls the controller below. The controller does what it needs to do (add Task to database) and calls the view showTasks. Till now,everything is fine. But here is my problem. The URL still shows /addTaskAction. So if I do a refresh or F5, the controller is again called and another task is added to database.
What is the cleanest/industry standard way of avoiding this? How to make sure that post form submit the URL shows /showTasks and not /addTaskAction.

...
Add

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addTaskAction", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTaskAction(@RequestParam("issueType") String issueType,            
        @RequestParam("priority") String priority,
        @RequestParam("summary") String summary,
        @RequestParam("reporter") String reporter,
        @RequestParam("assignee") String assignee,
        @RequestParam("status") String status,
        @RequestParam("comments") String comments,
        Model model) {
    System.out.println(issueType);
    Task task = new Task(issueType,priority,summary, reporter,
            assignee,status,comments);
    taskRepository.save(task);
    model.addAttribute("tasks", taskRepository.getAllTasks());
    //model.addAttribute("task", task);
    System.out.println("Tasks added-"+taskRepository.getAllTasks().size());
    return "showTasks";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not supposed to return a page from a `POST`, you're supposed to redirect to a different page, thus changing the url. In your example, you should probably have something like this:

```
return "redirect:showTasks";
```

This returns a redirect instruction to the browser, that then requests the page you've specified.

Comment: Dollery,Thanks for quick reply. So I can assume I was doing something conceptually wrong. Can you also point me to a URl or document where they discuss web app development best practises. (Like GET should not modify any data, POST should not return a page, etc). That would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Sure, here you go: http://en.wikipedia.org.advanc.io/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get+Newton